# Laravel Routing Error 404 /{slug} and parameter {domain}

Tags: laravel, routes

I have routes like this :

```
Route::resource('tunnels', 'TunnelController');
Route::get('/{slug}', array('uses' => 'TunnelController@show','as' => 'domain.tunnels.show'));
```

This is the route in my blade file

```
{{ route('domain.tunnels.show', ['slug' => $tunnel->slug])}}
```

It gives me url like this : http://maindomain.com/my-slug"

It works great !

Then, i want to use the customdomain.com, so i configure my routes like this

```
Route::resource('tunnels', 'TunnelController');
Route::get('/{slug}', array('domain' => '{domain}', 'uses' => 'TunnelController@show','as' => 'domain.tunnels.show'));
```

And the route

```
{{ route('domain.tunnels.show', ['domain' => $tunnel->domain, 'slug' => $tunnel->slug])}}
```

The render is of the url looks good : http://customdomain.com/my-slug
But when i try to open the page i get a 404 error.

I try to figure out why since 2 days, but i can't get it :(

Is there something i forgot ?

Thanks

EDIT :

TunnelController.php

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('auth', ['except' => 'show']);

}
public function show($slug)
{
$tunnel = Tunnel::where('slug', $slug)->first();
 return view('tunnels.show', ['tunnel' => $tunnel]);
}
```

Comment: Can you show the code in your TunnelController?

Comment: @djoo You need laravel `Dynamic custom domain routing`? if yes then I will post answer.

Comment: @AmitSenjaliya first i have a problem to get the tunnel object with my slug i supposed.
And then, yes i need dynamic custom domain routing (it works already to create the URL, but i get the 404)

Comment: @BartvanVenrooij i edit the post and put the content of tunnelController on the bottom :)

Comment: Did you add the getRouteKeyName method to your Tunnel model? @see https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/routing#implicit-binding

Comment: @djoo first route `{{ route('domain.tunnels.show', ['slug' => $tunnel->slug])}}` worked  fine?

Comment: @BartvanVenrooij Thanks. yes i did it. I don't understand, why when i use the dynamic custom domain i get a 404

Comment: @AmitSenjaliya yes it works well.
The problem is about the 404 with the custom domain :/

Comment: Is it a nginx 404 error page or laravel 404?

Comment: @djoo I have posted answer for a custom domain. can you try it?

Comment: @djoo  Need to create a `CNAME` record in the DNS settings for their domain to point it to the application. If you need to use `customdomain.com` instead of `maindomain.com`

Comment: @BartvanVenrooij laravel 404. I did the cname

Comment: @AmitSenjaliya
i think we get closer, but it still doesn't work.

{{ route('domain.tunnels.show', ['slug' => $tunnel->slug]) }} 
-> Give me this : http:/my-slug

So i tryied 
{{ route('domain.tunnels.show', ['domain' => $tunnel->domain, 'slug' => $tunnel->slug])}}
-> Give me this (great !) : http://customdomain.test/my-slug 

But then on the page, it's not able to load the slug
I did a dd($slug) in the show() function and i get "customdomain.test"

An issue with the regex ?

Comment: @djoo Yes I forgot to add  `domain` in the `route()` method. So now you have an issue with `slug`. Dynamic slug is not return using `$tunnel->slug` Right?

Comment: @AmitSenjaliya

Yep

public function show($slug)
    {
        dd($slug); //-> return "customdomain.text" and not the slug
        
        $tunnel = Tunnel::where('slug', $slug)->first();

        return view('tunnels.show', ['tunnel' => $tunnel]);
    }

Comment: I think that this is because your first param in your show method is now not the slug but the domain. If you would change it to `public function show(string $domain, string $slug)` then the $slug variable should contain your slug

Comment: this is it ! Thanks a lot guys :)

Comment: @djoo Glad that your issue solved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Dynamic custom domain routing in Laravel:**

You need to follow the below code:

```
Route::group(['domain' => '{domain}'], function() {
    Route::get('/{slug}', array('uses' => 'TunnelController@show','as' => 'domain.tunnels.show'));
});
```

the full domain name is passed to the route handler as a parameter named domain

```
{{ route('domain.tunnels.show', ['domain' => $tunnel->domain,'slug' => $tunnel->slug]) }}
```

In your project’s `app/Providers/RouteServiceProvider.php` file, changed the `boot` method to the following:

```
public function boot()
{
     \Route::pattern('domain', '[a-z0-9.\-]+'); 
     parent::boot();
}
```

In the controller TunnelController.php

```
public function show(string $domain, string $slug)
{
    $tunnel = Tunnel::where('slug', $slug)->first();
    return view('tunnels.show', ['tunnel' => $tunnel]);
}
```